# Pandas Only Exporting 1 Table to Excel but Printing all

Tags: python, excel, pandas, web-scraping

The code below only exports the last table on the page to excel, but when I run the print function, it will print all of them. Is there an issue with my code causing not to export all data to excel?

I've also tried exporting as .csv file with no luck.

```py
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.vegasinsider.com/college-football/matchups/'

dfs = pd.read_html(url)
for df in dfs:
    if len(df.columns) > 1: 
        df.to_excel(r'VegasInsiderCFB.xlsx', index = False)
        #print(df)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that each time `df.to_excel` is called, you are overwriting the file, so only the last df will be left. What you need to do is use a writer and specify a sheet name for each separate `df` e.g:

```py
url = 'https://www.vegasinsider.com/college-football/matchups/'
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('VegasInsiderCFB.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
dfs = pd.read_html(url)
counter = 0
for df in dfs:
    if len(df.columns) > 4:
        counter += 1
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = f"sheet_{counter}", index = False)
writer.save()
```

You might need `pip install xlsxwriter xlwt` to make it work.

Exporting to a csv will never work, since a csv is a single data table (like a single sheet in excel), so in that case you would need to use a new csv for each df.

As pointed out in the comments, it would be possible to write the data onto a single sheet without changing the `df`s, but it is likely much better to merge them:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
url = 'https://www.vegasinsider.com/college-football/matchups/'
dfs = pd.read_html(url)

dfs = [df for df in dfs if len(df.columns) > 4]
columns = ["gameid","game time", "team"] + list(dfs[0].iloc[1])[1:]
N = len(dfs)
values = np.empty((2*N,len(columns)),dtype=np.object)
for i,df in enumerate(dfs):
    time = df.iloc[0,0].replace(" Game Time","")
    values[2*i:2*i+2,2:] = df.iloc[2:,:]
    values[2*i:2*i+2,:2] = np.array([[i,time],[i,time]])
newdf = pd.DataFrame(values,columns = columns)

newdf.to_excel("output.xlsx",index = False)
```

I used a `numpy.array` of object type to be able to copy a submatrix from the original dataframes easily into their intended place. I also needed to create a `gameid`, that connects the games across rows. It should be now trivial to rewrite this so you loop through a list of urls and write these to separate sheets.

Comment: your code did get all the tables needed, so i reallly appreciate it, but is there a way to keep them all on the same sheet without making a sheet for each table? the goal is to scrape multiple sites and each of them have their own sheet. 

so sheet 1 would be VegasInsider, sheet 2 would be FanDuel, etc.

Comment: Not in general. The problem is that pandas dataframe is a NxM table basically, and one sheet can only be one dataframe. So you'd need to first merge all the dfs from say VegasInsider into a single dataframe, which is only possible if all of them look the same.

Comment: @fbence, Merging the data frames is probably the best option but it is possible to put more than one dataframe on a single sheet: https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_pandas_positioning.html

Comment: @jmcnamara Thanks, I totally didn't know about that!

Comment: I checked the data and all of them look the same, so I agree with @jmcnamara, for any analysis purpose, merging the dataframes would be the way to go, I'll hack it together shortly.

Comment: Thank you, everyone. This worked! Going to do some reading on numbpy with pandas and test on other sites. Really, really appreciate this.